# Splitting Strings in java around the '|' character

Tags: java, string, split

I have this

```
String str = "a,pnp,a|pnp,lab2|pnp,a|pnp,lab2,utr,utr";
String[] strings = str.split("|");
```

This code won't split around the '|' character, instead it splits every character like

```
strings[0] == "a";
strings[1] == ",";
```

and so on.

How to get this working to get

```
strings[0] == "a,pnp,a"
strings[1] == "pnp,lab2"
...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`split()` takes a regular expression, and `|` is reserved for regex OR, so you need to escape it:

```
String[] strings = str.split("\\|");
```

or even better:

```
String[] strings = str.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

Comment: +1: this is the link to the documentation:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html (Logical Operators)

Answer (score 1):

use

```
String[] strings = str.split("\\|");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could escape the `|` symbol, as other answers have showed. Personally I'd suggest downloading [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com) and using [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v11.0.2/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) instead. While that may be seen as overkill for a single statement, in my experience it would be a rare project which couldn't be made more readable by various bits of Guava.

I'd personally use a list instead of an array if possible, so:

```
private static final Splitter PIPE_SPLITTER = Splitter.on('|');
...

// Or an immutable list if you don't plan on changing it afterwards
List<String> strings = Lists.newArrayList(PIPE_SPLITTER.split(str));
```

It's possible that I'm just overly-allergic to regular expressions, but I really don't like using an API which deals with regular expressions unless I'm *really* trying to use patterns which warrant them.

Answer (score 0):

public String[] split(String regex)

Splits this string around matches of the given regular expression.

This method works as if by invoking the two-argument split method with the given expression and a limit argument of zero. Trailing empty strings are therefore not included in the resulting array.

So, you should try String[] arrayOfStrings = str.split("\|");

Answer (score 0):

Just to the add to the options of escaping the `|` character:

```
String[] strings = str.split("[|]");
```